# Find difference between two 3D shapes using devDept Eyeshot

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, cad, eyeshot

What's the best algorithm to find the difference in two three dimensional shapes loaded in devDept Eyeshot?

I have loaded the two shapes from CAD files in Eyeshot and want to highlight the difference in the shapes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What object types are you comparing? Mesh, Solid, Surface or Solid3D?

Comment: HI @Alberto it's a mesh

Comment: How would you like to display the differences? Booleans result, colormap or what else?

Comment: Is this question still active?  I have several ideas but similarly to abenci need more description of what your desired output would be /  look like.

Answer (score 7):

So, here is a quick way of doing it. (At least what I think you're asking for)
This function will take meshA and subtract any overlapping volume of meshB out of it.
It returns a List of Meshes, as it is possible to "chop" meshA into multiple pieces by subtracting a single volume.  I think the difference function will organize pieces by volume into the list, but I am NOT 100% on that.

```
public List<Mesh> solidSubtract(ref Mesh meshA, ref Mesh meshB)
{
  List<Mesh> subtractedMeshes = new List<Mesh>();
  Solid solidA = meshA.ConvertToSolid();
  Solid solidB = meshB.ConvertToSolid();
  Solid[] difference = Solid.Difference(solidA, solidB);
  foreach (Solid sld in difference)
  {
    subtractedMeshes.Add(sld.ConvertToMesh());
  }
  return subtractedMeshes;
}
```